# web service serialization problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, web-services, xml-serialization

I have a web service. A method of this web service, returns WSSonuc class.

```
 [Serializable]
public class WSSonuc
{

    public int M_Durum { get; set; }
    public object M_SonucNesne { get; set; }
}
```

this is my Web service method:

```
 [WebMethod]
 [SoapHeader("_ticket", Direction = SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
public WSSonuc f_Dummy()
{
  WSSonuc ws = new WSSonuc();
  ws.M_Durum = 1;
  ws.M_SonucNesne = new XDocument();
  return ws;
}
```

I have an exception from web site when i call f_Dummy; Exception is :

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.Xml.Linq.XDocument was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) isn't XML serializable.  You could substitute [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) instead since this class is marked as `IXMLSerializable`.

If you decide to do that, it's probably important you realize the differences of these two objects.  [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx) seems like a good place to start (in addition to the links I placed above to MSDN).

Alternatively, you could fall back on good ole' [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

When you will find proper class to pass, you need also to declare which objects could be returned (on Webservice class or method Level) using **XmlIncludeAttribute**

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(ANyDerivedType1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(ANyDerivedType2))]
public WSSonuc f_Dummy()
```